# how to handle push notification even if app is closed in swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

In my app i need to access push notification payload without user interaction even if app is closed. I used `launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification]` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. But the problem is when notification comes, sometimes `launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification]` contains payloads or sometimes not.why?

My code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` are given below:

```
if launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] != nil 
{

            UserDefaults.standard.set(launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification], forKey: "NotificationDetails")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

            handlePushNotificationUserInfo(userInfo: launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as! [AnyHashable : Any])
        }
```

In above code, Sometimes I get notification payload in `UserDefaults` or Sometimes not.

Comment: it could be because there is no data for NotificationDetails in payload.

Answer (score 0):

You will only get if the user taps on the notification. I put my below which I used to a notification, I didn't get any issue. You can check my code.

```
if let launchOptions = launchOptions {
    if let info = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] {
        let dic = info as! NSDictionary
    }
}
```